# How to write Inline style for text in OpenOffice.org

Tags: openoffice.org

I am aware of style in  OpenOffice.org

< office:automatic-styles > .... < office:automatic-styles />

but

I want inline style same like HTML style,

like

< text:span style="color:" >< /text:span > (something like that)....is this possible?

if you know such example or article then please ref me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For LibreOffice 4 (probably applies to earlier versions and/or OpenOffice too):

Code:

1. In styles.xml: in <office:styles>

   ```
   <style:style style:name="STYLE_NAME" style:family="text">
        <style:text-properties style:font-name="DejaVu Sans Mono1" ... />
   </style:style>
   ```
2. In content.xml:

   ```
   <text:span text:style-name="STYLE_NAME">abc def ghi jkl</text:span>
   ```

WYSIWYG:

1. Apply styles on a standard text and select it
2. Open Styles and Formatting (from *Format menu* -> *Styles and Formatting* or press F11)
3. Switch to Character Styles tab (second one, with "a")
4. Use last button or the right side, *New Style from Selection*

Whenever you select text, currently used inline style will be highlighted in *Styles and Formatting* window. To apply a style, select text and double-click the style in the *Styles and Formatting* window.

Sorry the answer comes so late, I was just wondering myself and eventually found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Discovered this and led me to more user-friendly solution in newer version 6.x

At the top of the Styles panel (sidebar), the default selection is Paragraph styles.
Selct the adjoining Character Styles, and you have access to creating, modifying and applying inline styles.